# Wordpress– How to include custom post type content in a template?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using a custom post type and have got it to show up in the Wordpress admin area. This is part of my functions code:

```
//CUSTOM POST TYPE
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'slick_slider',
  array(
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Main Slider' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Slider' )
  ),
  'public' => true,
  'has_archive' => true,
)
);
}
```

My problem is that I need to insert these custom post types into a template. I've tried using this code to do that:

```
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
     <?php $slick_slider_values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'slick_slider' ); ?>
 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

But it does not work. Any idea what code I need to get the CPTs to display correctly within the template page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a Custom Post Type so you need to do a custom post type loop:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=slick_slider&posts_per_page=5'); if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
// normal post stuff here ie <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This goes outside the loop! Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'   => 'slick_slider',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
 );

$slick_slider = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $slick_slider->have_posts() ) :

      while( $slick_slider->have_posts() ) : $slick_slider->the_post();

            $slick_slider_values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'slick_slider' );

      endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Unfortunately it does not seem to be working for me. It doesn't display anything on the page. I tried it inside a loop and that just generated an error. Any ideas?

Comment: it won't display anything, this is just the loop and you need to build your markup inside.

Answer (score 0):

You've need to use WP_Query if you want to show any post type or post outside of single post file or outside of the page template. So use the following code instead.

```
$slider = new WP_Query(array(
             'post_type'   => 'slick_slider',
          ));
if( $slider->have_posts() ){
      while( $slider->have_posts() ) {
        $slider->the_post();
        $slider_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'slick_slider' );
    }
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Hope that it'll help you.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I tried it and it is not working. It doesn't render anything on the page. Does it need to be inside the loop to work?